# Hide action bar in NativeScript Angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

From NativeScript official documentation:

> Тhе actionBarVisibility is a property that controls the visibility of the Navigation Bar in iOS and the Action Bar in Android for the current Frame. It should be set directly to the Frame and has three option values auto, never, always.

```
<Frame id="my-frame-id" actionBarVisibility="never" defaultPage="home/home-page"/>
```

But I found no Frame tag in NativeScript Angular.

Where can I found it? Or how do I hide action bar in NativeScript Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `actionBarVisibility` to the `page-router-outlet` element in the `app.component.html` like the snippet below:

```html
<page-router-outlet actionBarVisibility="never"></page-router-outlet>
```

To hide it for specific pages you can set the `actionBarHidden` property of the `Page` class like the snippet below:

```js
import { Page } from '@nativescript/core';

@Component({
...
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private page: Page) {
    page.actionBarHidden = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! May I ask how do I hide it on selected pages, instead of hiding it on every page?

Comment: Updated my answer to include that